# Getting error for @dropdownlistFor".. item that has the key 'product' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The ViewModel is:

```
namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels
{
    public class WorkFlowTestViewModel
    {
        public string processInstance { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
        public string selectedProd { get; set; }
        public int product { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller is:

```
public class WorkFlowTestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /WorkFlowTest/
    public ActionResult OpenSubmission(string processId, string mailId, ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel SubmissionModelView)
    {

        SubmissionModelView.processInstance = processId;
        SubmissionModelView.mail = mailId;
        SubmissionModelView.products = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
             new SelectListItem{ Text = "GL", Value = "1" } , 
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Property", Value = "2", Selected = true },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Package", Value = "3" },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Island Marine", Value = "4" }

        };

        return View("Submission", SubmissionModelView);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ProductSubmission(ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel SubmissionModelView)
    {
        var prod = SubmissionModelView.product;
        return View("Submission", SubmissionModelView);
    }
}
```

The part of view is :

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("#addProd").click(function() {

            alert("here");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/WorkFlowTest/ProductSubmission",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.success);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
    });
});

</script>


<tr>
                    <td style="width: 313px"> <label for="Product Code">  
       Product Code:&nbsp;</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
 model.product  , @Model.products)%></td>
<td style="width: 313px"><input type ="button" id="addProd" value ="Add Product" /></td>
</tr>
```

The application is in .Net 3.5 and MVC 2 for ,net 3.5

The `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.product  , @Model.products)` gets populated for first time when called. This works fine.

In the view I have jquery which posts the form and the controller with this method is called.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ProductSubmission(ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel SubmissionModelView)
```

This time when the view is rendered I get run time error pointing at the drop down list:

```
<%=@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.product  , @Model.products)%> with error:
```

> The ViewData item that has the key 'product' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Please can some one help.

Answer (score 0):

`SubmissionModelView.product` is set somewhere to an `int` instead of a `List`, most likely right before or in `ProductSubmission()`.